# How to increase the speed of log4net logging

Tags: performance, log4net

We're using FileAppender of log4net to capture logs, and for some reasons, we need to log a lot of information. We also separate logs based on their types and levels (debug, info, error, etc.)

However, we have measured our I/O and we know that it's part of the latency of our system. We intend to increase logging performance. Here are the options available to us:

1. Using asynchronous logging
2. Using bulk logging

We want to make sure that it does not support bulk logging first, then we can go to other mechanisms. How can we increase its performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a BufferingForwardingAppender in-between your logger and your appender it will reduce your IO from each log to the size of the batch.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.12/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender.html

Also checkout Log4Net.Async and the Log4Net.Async.AsyncRollingFileAppender class